# How do I cook roasts?

Tags: achievements, psychonauts

Steam's holiday sale added the "Holiday Dinner" achievement to Psychonauts.  The description is:

> Cook and consume two different kinds of roast in one sitting.

I played through about half the game previously before getting distracted, and remember nothing about cooking roasts.  Where do I go to cook a roast, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Use Pyrokinesis on a Squirrel to make a Squirrel Roast.
2. Use Pyrokinesis on a bird to make your second roast.

Roasts are eaten right when they are picked up.  **Both animals must be eaten in the same area, without transitioning.**

Comment: Can anyone suggest alternative animals? All saves I have in this game are in the night period, and there doesn't seem to be any birds at night.

Comment: If all your saves are in the night, start a new game. Use a cheat code to unlock all psi powers and then do as said above.

Comment: thanks i was looking for this answer i got 6 coals and needed this one more to get a free game in steam

Comment: How long does it take for steam to know when the above achieve ment of 2 roasts in 1 sitting has been accomplished. Steam is currently running that offer Gift Pile - where i ahve 6 coals and needed just 1 more - this one - 2 roasts in 1 sitting to get to 7 and thus get a game, so i managed to ahieve it after looking at this page, but the gift pile still hasn't unlocked and my coals are still at 6 istead of 7